# Batch rename files using find in content

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-rename

Long-time listener first-time caller.

I'm trying to use a windows batch script to search for specific strings in files contained in a directory, and classify them with a file name and random value for further processing.

This is what I have put together based on similar posts:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%a in (C:\Temp\*.txt) do (

  set t1=string1-%RANDOM%.txt

  set t2=string2-%RANDOM%.txt

  find "string1" %%~fa && ren %%~fa %t1%

  find "string2" %%~fa && ren %%~fa %t2%

)
```

If I move the set commands outside the for loop it will work, but I need it to generate a random file name within the loop in case there's multiple files found with 'string1'.

Any help much appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In cmd, variables are replaced with it value when the block in which they are placed is readed. In your case, your set variables are replaced once, when the for is readed, and changes are not visible because once that replacement is done, there is no more variable replacement. That is the reason for the `enabledelayedexpansion`, but a change in code is needed

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%a in (C:\Temp\*.txt) do (
  set t1=string1-!RANDOM!.txt
  set t2=string2-!RANDOM!.txt
  find "string1" "%%~fa" && ren "%%~fa" !t1!
  find "string2" "%%~fa" && ren "%%~fa" !t2!
)
```

For delayed expansion of variables, it is necessary to indicate to cmd which of the variables should be replaced in each access. To do it, change % with ! when using the variable. This is not necessary for control variables in `for` command (your `%%a`), for which it is assumed.

Be careful, your code does not handle the posibility of duplicate file names. Random means random, not unique. Collisions are possible.